# Excercise 4.B.4 from M.Isaacs Finite Group Theory book. Commutators identity

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, normal-subgroups

I try to solve the following problem.

> Let $X,Y$ be subgroups of finite group $G$, and $Y$ centralizes
>   $[X,Y]$.
>
> 1. Prove that $[Y,Y]$ centralizes $X$.
> 2. Now assume that $X$ is normal in $G$. Show that $[X,Y]$ is abelian.

The first item can be solved by applying the three subgroup lemma. But I don't know how to solve the second item. I give here my attempt (not rigorous and maybe not correct)
$$
[[X,Y],[X,Y]] = [[X,Y],[Y,X]]\subseteq [X,Y,Y,X] = [[[X,Y],Y],X] =1.
$$
We know that for every finite group $F$ the following inclusion is valid $$[F^i,F^j]\subseteq F^{i+j},$$
where $F^i=[F,F,\ldots,F]$ ($i$-times). But I don't know is it possible to prove the analogous inclusion $[[A,B],[C,D]]\subseteq [A,B,C,D]$ for arbitrary subgroups of $F$ or maybe
$[[A,B],[A,C]]\subseteq [A,B,A,C]$, when $A$ is normal in $F$.

Comment: $[[Y,[X,Y]],X]=1$ and $[[[X,Y],X],Y] \le [[X,Y],Y]=1$ so by the $3$-subgroups lemma $[[X,Y],[X,Y]]=1$, but I don't seem to have used the normality of $X$ in $G$.

Comment: Thank you, Derek! The normality condition really confused me =)